# How can i read the text from files?

Tags: c#

I have two txt files, and i need using stream reader, consider text in one txt until it finished in other txt. It means that if first txt is finished, but the second txt is not finished, then software continue again first txt until the second will not finished.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Wiz\Desktop\first part.txt");
        StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\Wiz\Desktop\second part.txt");

        string file, files1;

        while (true)
        {
            file = sr.ReadLine();
            if (file == null) break;
            files1 = sr1.ReadLine();
            if (files1 == null) break;

            Console.WriteLine(file + files1);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere i have already wrote the code

Comment: OK, well you need to check if you have finished the files - are they always going to be the same size?

Comment: @BugFinder "It means that if first txt is finished, but the second txt is not finished" Obviously not.

Comment: You could try using `File.ReadAllText(..) `

Comment: if first txt content 1 2 3, and the second content a b c d e f g. It means that stream will continue again, like so 1a 1b 3c 1d 1f 1g until the second stream will not be finished

Comment: You have to re-initialize the reader if one file is finsihed while the other not. But before re-opening tzhe file dispose the previos reader.

Comment: What happens when file2 is finished but file1 not? Should software continue re-reading file2 also?

Comment: @HimBromBeere nothing, simply readkey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using *Linq*:

```
// Since we should be ready to read/re-read the 1st file again and again
// Let´s materialize the file 
var file1 = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Wiz\Desktop\first part.txt");

var target = File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\Wiz\Desktop\second part.txt")
  .Select((line, index) => file1[index % file1.Length] + line);

Console.Write(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, target));
```

Comment: underline this part `index % file1.Count`

Comment: @komra23: since `file1` can be shorter than `file2` you have to use modular arithemtics while indexing

Comment: @komra23: I'm sorry for typo: it should be `file1.Length`, not `file1.Count`

Answer (score 0):

So concidering that i got the question right (you want to first read ALL the lines of file 1, before start reading file 2) i´d suggest using:

```
file1 = sr.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Wiz\Desktop\first part.txt");
file2 = sr1.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Wiz\Desktop\second part.txt");
Console.WriteLine(file1 + file2);
```

Documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms143368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: one question yet: how can i make replace according alphabet for string, it means if i have strings which start with aaa, and then there should be baa then instead of baa should be caa and so on

Comment: You want to replace a certain character with another?